# calling download.php inside another php

Tags: php, html

I have a button wrapped inside a form action, which upon click calls the below download.php and downloads the file which is already present.

form action inside results.php

```
<form method="post" action="download.php">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-block" data-toggle="dwn-one" title="Click to download"> Download </button>
     </form>
```

download.php

```
<?php
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=file1.txt");
        header("Content-type: application/txt");
        readfile("file1.txt");
        header("results.php");
?>
```

The above functionality is working fine, but now I have many files to download, so I want to avoid multiple download buttons, instead provide a select function, where user can select the file and click the download button. So far I am doing like below, but unable to figure out, how to call download.php.

Code for select

```
<form method = "post" action="">
   <select class="form-control" name="downloaditem">
        <option value="1">Select a file to download</option>
        <option value="2">File one</option>
        <option value="3">File two</option>
        <option value="4">File three</option>
        <option value="5">File four</option>
      </select>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="files">Download</button>
</form>
```

the isset function

```
if(isset($_POST['files']))
{
        $filesel = $_POST['downloaditem'];
        if($filesel == "2")
        {
      //call to download.php
        }
}
```

Please help.

Thanks,
Karthic

Comment: Maybe `header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=file{$_POST['downloaditem']}.txt");` and keep it the same. This doesnt consider any security concerns though.

Comment: It seems that you'd serve the file the same way you did before. What seems to be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just send the form to the download.php script.

```html
<form method = "post" action="<url-to>download.php">
   <select class="form-control" name="downloaditem">
        <!-- It's not necessary to make the first option available for select -->
        <option value="0" disabled>Select a file to download</option>
        <option value="1">File one</option>
        <option value="2">File two</option>
        <option value="3">File three</option>
        <option value="4">File four</option>
      </select>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="files">Download</button>
</form>
```

download.php

```php
// Get the file name and path to the file based on the given id
// or return null
function getFile($id) {
    switch((int)$_POST['downloaditem']) {
        case 1:
            return ['file1', 'path/to/file1.txt'];
        case 2:
            return ['file1', 'path/to/file2.txt'];
        case 3:
            return ['file1', 'path/to/file3.txt'];
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['files'])) {
    $file = getFile($_POST['downloaditem']);
    if (null !== $file} {
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $file[0]. '.txt');
        header('Content-Type: application/txt');
        readfile($file[2]);
        header('results.php');
    } else {
        // If function returns null show a HTTP 404 error
        header('Content-Type: text/plain');
        header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
    }
}
```